# Webscraping to download unique PDF files

Tags: python, excel, pdf

I have to routinely download over 300 pdfs from over 150 websites once every quarter, and I've been starting to think there has to be automate this using python. These PDFs are released on a quarterly basis, and detail the performance of mutual funds over the previous quarter. 90% of the time, these PDFs are called 'quarterly commentary' or 'commentary', and so what I want to do is write a script in python to search the fund-specific url ex (https://www.pimco.com/investments/mutual-funds/total-return-fund/inst) for the keyword 'commentary', find the link, and then download the resulting PDF file.

I would also like to name the download file to coincide with the proper mutual fund name. Now what I have been working off of is an excel spreadsheet. In column A I have the proper mutual fund name. In column B I have the mutual fund URL.

Would this be possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I find it easier to use CaspjerJS and PhantomJS to download files from external websites because you can inject javascript code into the page to grab the elements you need.

[Here is the casperjs documentation](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/index.html)

And here is some code that I've written to download lectures from my professors webpage and download them to my desktop:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({verbose: true , logLevel: "debug" });
var url = "https://www.cs.rit.edu/~ib/Classes/CSCI264_Fall16-17/assignments.html";
var fs = require('fs');
casper.start(url);
var elements; 
casper.then(function(){
    elements = this.evaluate(function(){ 
        var pdfs =  document.querySelectorAll('body ul li a'); 
        return Array.prototype.map.call(pdfs, function(e) {
            return e.getAttribute('href');
        });
    });
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i){
        var url = "" + elements[i] + "";
        if(url.indexOf('pdf') !== -1){
            var file = fs.absolute(url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/")+1, url.length));          
            this.download(url, file);   
        }
    }   
});


casper.run(function() {
    this.echo('Done.').exit();
});
```

Of course if you're deadset on using python then disregard this completely. Otherwise, good-luck with your CasperJS script.

Comment: Thank you for this, I will look into CasperJS. Definitely not deadset on python.. I just have the most experience with it!

Comment: I'm getting a code800a138f error when I try to your script above. Is it possible that I did not install casperjs or phantomjs correctly which is why I'm getting the error?

Comment: make sure you install phantomjs and casperjs globally with npm using the `-g` flag. Also I've been running mine on a Mac through the terminal, I don't know how much this differs if you're using a windows machine